how to return value from aws connect module to contact flow. values are accessesible in module but not in contact flow
calling lambda from module returning json that is accessible in module flow but not in parent contact flow. Also set contract attribute block doesn't setting up in user define value , only can accesss as external value
module - lambda - json -- external accessible but not user defined in module. also both not accessible in contact flow
